# How to list down all tables in a schema in sybase?

Tags: sql, database, sybase

How can I list down all the tables that are present in a schema in Sybase?

In oracle `SELECT* FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES` works. I'm looking for a similar approach for sybase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below by using `sysobjects`

```
select *
from sysobjects
```

and below will return your all tables of current database

```
select convert(varchar(30),o.name) AS table_name
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U'
order by table_name
```

[Sybase docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/X14933.htm)

Comment: This gives all the tables in the database but how do I classify it according to the schema? There is no column that denotes the schema that table is in.

Comment: @YatharthSurana add where clause and filter by using your schema name

Comment: @YatharthSurana answer edited you can check is that works for u or not

Comment: The db user I was using didn't have the required access due to which it didn't work the first time. Changing the user made it work! thank you